# React native returning typeerror:null is not an object(evaluating feeds.length)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I dont know what is wrong with this react native app that am creating that is returning the above error and I can't really say this is what is wrong with the code. 
What I want to do is check if the numbers of feed is greater than zero(0) and if it is, display the content(s) and if not display

> No saved feeds

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native'

import CenterMessage from '../components/CenterMessage'

import { colors } from '../theme'

export default class Feeds extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Feeds',
    headerTitleStyle: {
      color: 'white',
      fontSize: 20,
      fontWeight: '400'
    }
  }
  navigate = (item) => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Feed', { feed: item })
  }
  render() {
    const { screenProps: { feeds } } = this.props
    return (
      <ScrollView  contentContainerStyle={[!feeds.length && { flex: 1 }]}>// error here !feeds.length
        <View style={[!feeds.length && { justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }]}>// error here !feeds.length
          {
            !feeds.length && <CenterMessage message='No saved feeds!' />// error here !feeds.length
          }
          {
            feeds.map((item, index) => (
              <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.navigate(item)} key={index} >
                <View style={styles.feedContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.feed}>{item.feed}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.country}>{item.country}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ))
          }
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  feedContainer: {
    padding: 10,
    borderBottomWidth: 2,
    borderBottomColor: colors.primary
  },
  feed: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
  country: {
    color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)'
  },  
})
```

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

[image: screen 3]
[image]

Comment: What do you get when you log `feeds`?

Comment: I have added an image of what I got

Comment: What version of react-navigation are you using?

Comment: @Ziyo react-navigation 2.0.1